# Queueable class Too many SOQL queries: 201

Tags: apex, soql, callout, limits, queueable-apex

I need to create a HTTPPost method to generate a report so when I did it at first, I had exceeded the number of queries limit so I implemented a queuable class to solve the issue as I have read in the documentation.

I am implementing Queueable class to return data to the callout as below:

```
//part of the HTTPPOST class  calling the queuable class                                           
    f_API_C_generateContactReport report = new f_API_C_generateContactReport(mycontact.id);
    ID jobID = System.enqueueJob(report);

    string result = report.getResult(); 
        
    res.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(result);
    
    res.statusCode = 200;
```

What is happening is that report.getResult() is being called before the queuable class finishes so no result is available. In addition, when I tried to initialize my returned resulted so I won't get a null in the result, I got an error in my queuable class: Too many SOQL queries: 201

Queuable class:

```
//part of the queuable class                                                                                                                  
 public class f_API_C_generateContactReport implements Queueable {

private string conId;
private string reportResult = 'DefaultValue';

public f_API_C_generateContactReport(string conId) 
{ 
    this.conId = conId;
}

public void execute(QueueableContext context){
    List<pba__Property__c> propertyList = new List<pba__Property__c>();
    propertyList = [select id, yield__c from pba__Property__c 
                    where List_Of_Beneficiary_Contacts_Id__c like: '%' + conId + '%'];
    
    Map<String, object> myResult = new Map<String, object>();
    myResult.put('yearlyCashFlow', getYearlyCashFlow(propertyList));
    myResult.put('yieldByProperty', getPropertyYield(propertyList));
    myResult.put('duePaymentsByClosing', getDuePayment(propertyList));
    
    AggregateResult[] propertyByTypeAgg = [select pba__PropertyType__c, COUNT(Id)cnt from pba__Property__c  
                                           where  List_Of_Beneficiary_Contacts_Id__c like: '%' + conId + '%'
                                             GROUP BY pba__PropertyType__c
                                             ORDER BY COUNT(Id) DESC];
    
    AggregateResult[] propertyByStatusAgg = [select Status__c, COUNT(Id)cnt from pba__Property__c 
                                             where  List_Of_Beneficiary_Contacts_Id__c like: '%' + conId + '%'
                                             GROUP BY Status__c
                                             ORDER BY COUNT(Id) DESC];  
    
    AggregateResult[] propertyByCityAgg = [select pba__City_pb__c, COUNT(Id)cnt from pba__Property__c 
                                           where  List_Of_Beneficiary_Contacts_Id__c like: '%' + conId + '%'
                                           GROUP BY pba__City_pb__c
                                           ORDER BY COUNT(Id) DESC]; 

    myResult.put('propertyByType',propertyByTypeAgg);
    myResult.put('propertyByStatus',propertyByStatusAgg);
    myResult.put('propertyByCity',propertyByCityAgg);
    
    this.reportResult = JSON.serialize(myResult);
    system.debug('i m here' + getResult());                                   
}

public string getResult()
{
    return this.reportResult;
}
```

Could you please tell me then first if I made the right decision by implementing a queuable class and second, if yes, how to solve the two problems I have.

Thanks

Comment: Queueable methods won't execute until *after* the transaction completes. Your design is therefore flawed. You will need to bulkify your code if you want to do this synchronously. Putting a query in a method that is called in a loop is a Bad Idea. This code is possible to do, but will take a pretty significant rewrite.

Comment: I was able to avoid the SOQL limit by reducing the number of loops and optimizing the code. But I am still facing an issue that the response of the exposes class is returning before the end of the job in the queue. I have tried to add a loop to check if the result string is not empty thus the job has ended but I faced a CPU timeout. So any idea how to return the response when the job has ended? @sfdcfox

Comment: Again, Queueable classes cannot start running until the transaction completes. You will need to call this code directly without using Schedulable, Batchable, Queueable, or Future methods.